# Segue not found after replacing the view controller of Detail VC in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

New to iOS development. Practicing `UISplitViewController`. I have a master-detail app. Where `MasterVC` is a `UITableViewController` which acts as applications' nav. I am replacing the `DetailVC` with a new view controller according to what navigation item is clicked.

**MasterTableViewController**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detailVC = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1]

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:

            detailVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user_accvc_segue", sender: detailVC)

        case 1:
            detailVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user_projvc_segue", sender: detailVC)
        default:
            print("helalav")
        }
    }
```

I have storyboard segues setup from `DetailViewController` to two view controllers `AccountVC` & `ProjectsVC`.

The problem is that after selecting whatever navigation item from the nav. DetailVC is replaced by whatever was selected (either account or projects). But switching to another nav item afterwards says segue with identifier not found.

The reason for this is that new view controller has no such segue becuase it was actually defined on `DetailVC`

How can I overcome this situation? Or I should I use some other approach to replace view controllers in detail side?

Comment: I have fixed this one by using `showDetailViewController` of `UISplitViewController` instead of performing a segue explicitly. Will update the answer soon. But still would love to hear more on this situation. Ref https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621432-showdetailviewcontroller